# How is index out of range in this case?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am trying to build a function that replaces the date column of a data frame with a regex.

```
# import regex
import re

# create a copy of data
data2 = data
loop = len(data2) - data['Date of Publication'].isna().sum()
for i in range (loop):
   if (pd.notna(data2.loc[i]["Date of Publication"])):

        # copy the content of the date into old-value
        old_value = data2.loc[i]["Date of Publication"]

        # regex to match the first 4 digits of the old_value
        new_value = re.findall("\d{4}", str(old_value))

        # replace the old value
        data2.loc[i, 'Date of Publication'] = new_value[0]
```

it gives the error

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-be514cf910bf> in <module>()
     15 
     16         # replace the old value
---> 17         data2.loc[i, 'Date of Publication'] = new_value[0]
     18 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Since this isn't a program we can run, its just a guess, but does `new_value` have anything in it? What if `re.findall("\d{4}", str(old_value))` doesn't find anything?

Comment: You could try `data2.loc[i:, 'Date of Publication'] = new_value[0]`. I just added a colon.

Answer (score 1):

In python, `data2.loc[a, b]` is not the same thing as `data2.loc[a][b]`.  Your last line of code uses an incorrect form of indexing.

`data2.loc[a,b]` is a shorthand for `data2.loc[(a, b)]`, with the index being a single tuple.  Numpy may be confusing you, because it checks for the index being a tuple, and deals with it in the expected way.